# Remove next-to-last extension in a file name

Tags: shell, shell-script, sed, filenames, rename

Suppose a folder with many files with bad extensions,for example

```
Song1.avi.mp3
Song2.avi.mp3
Song32.web.mp3
Song23.mp4.mp3
Song2a.mp9.mp3
```

I want to remove only the second field (`web`, `avi`, `mp4`). I know how to do with sed but I have to put the extension

```
 mv -v $i "$(echo $i|sed 's:.flv::g;s:.avi::g;s:.mp4::g')"
```

Does someone know an immediate method with sed or awk or perl to remove only the second bad extension?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need any external utility, you can do it with the [shell's own string manipulation functionality](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). This makes it easier to avoid breaking on file names with special characters. And remember to [always use double quotes around variable substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

```
mv -v -- "$i" "${i%.*.*}.${i##*.}"
```

(Obviously this snippet assumes that the file name does contain two extensions. If it doesn't, `${i%.*.*}` would be the whole file name.)

Answer (score 6):

Using a bash regex:

```
f=foo.bar.baz.qux
if [[ $f =~ (.+)\.[^.]+\.([^.]+)$ ]];then
    new="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    if [[ -f "$new" ]]; then
        echo "moving $f would overwrite $new"
    else
        echo mv "$f" "$new"
    fi
fi
```

```
mv foo.bar.baz.qux foo.bar.qux
```

This has the advantage of doing nothing if there are less than 2 dots in the name.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to validate a filename match - and so only rename those files which actually have the two extensions you're attempting to modify - you can just do:

```
case ${i##*/} in (*.*.*)
mv -- "$i" "${i%.*.*}.${i##*.}"
;;esac
```

Understand that if you do not validate the match and you're setting `"$i"` with a glob like:

```
for i in *
mv "$i" ...
```

...then using the same `mv` command as above *(and in other answers)* could result in the file being moved to `"$i.$i"` as the var expands to itself if the pattern does not match.

Answer (score 4):

Easy rename with `mmv` command:

```
$ mmv -n '*.*.*' '#1.#3'
```

or with `rename` command:

```
$ rename -n 's:(.*)\..*(\..*):$1$2:' *
```